# Delete member from a Viber group

Tags: viber-messenger

I have created a group for chat on Viber and one person joined the group.

How can I remove that person?

Answer (score 1):

Viber doesn't provide facility to delete or remove member from group even if your are group admin.

Only option is you leave and delete group and recreate the group without that member.
Sorry

Comment: Damn viber for that.

Answer (score -2):

just tap and hold the name which u want to delete, a recycle icon will appear , then recycle it that it